# Adonuxt.js my js libraries are not being called from static folder

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, adonis.js

I am new to Nuxt.js, learning by developing a pilot project where in two different route, I included two different demo templates.

For that, I needed different js libraries and css to be included!

Here is how I did include into `nuxt.js` file!

```
link: [

      // vendor 
      {
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href: '/vendor/css/bootstrap.min.css'
      },

      {
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.min.css'
      },
      {
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href: 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css'
      },
      {
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px'
      },
      {
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href: '/vendor/css/bootstrap.min.css'
      },
      {
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href: '/vendor/css/owl.carousel.min.css'
      },
      {
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href: '/vendor/css/owl.theme.default.min.css'
      },
      {
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href: '/vendor/css/style.css'
      },


      // retail 
      {
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href: '/retail/css/bootstrap.min.css'
      },
      {
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href: '/retail/style.css'
      },
      {
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href: '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700%7CMontserrat:300,400,600,700'
      },
      {
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href: '/retail/icons/fontawesome/css/fontawesome-all.min.css'
      },{
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href: '/retail/icons/Iconsmind__Ultimate_Pack/Line%20icons/styles.min.css'
      },
    ],

    script:[

      // vendor
      { src: 'vendor/js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js', body: true },
      { src: 'vendor/js/popper.min.js', body: true },
      { src: 'vendor/js/bootstrap.min.js', body: true },
      { src: 'vendor/js/owl.carousel.min.js', body: true },
      { src: 'vendor/js/custom.js', body: true },
      { src: 'vendor/js/custom-vendor.js', body: true },
      { src: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js', body: true },


      // retail

      { src: 'retail/js/libs/jquery-3.3.1.min.js', body: true },
      { src: 'retail/js/libs/popper.min.js', body: true },
      { src: 'retail/js/libs/bootstrap.min.js', body: true },
      { src: 'retail/js/navigation.js', body: true },
      { src: 'retail/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js', body: true },
      { src: 'retail/js/jquery-asRange.min.js', body: true },
      { src: 'retail/js/circle-progress.min.js', body: true },
      { src: 'retail/js/afterglow.min.js', body: true },
      { src: 'retail/js/script.js', body: true },
      { src: 'retail/js/script-dashboard.js', body: true }
]
```

Here is my directory Structure of Pages:

```
├── pages
|   ├── retail
|       └── bank.vue
|       └── index.vue
|       └── info.vue
|   ├── vendor
|       └── index.vue
|   ├── index.vue
```

Here is my directory Structure of Static folder where I included all my js libraries and css files:

```
├── static
|   ├── retail
|       └── css
            ....
|       └── icons
            ....
|       └── images
            ....
|       └── js
|           └── jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js
                ....
|       └── style.css
|
|   ├── vendor
|       └── css
            ....
|       └── images
            ....
|       └── js
|           └── jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js
                ....
|       └── style.css
            ....
```

Thus I am expecting to go '/vendor' and load vendor stuffs, and same as the '/retail'.

But whenever page 'vendor' or 'retail' any of one page loads, all the javascript libraries are called in the following route:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/vendor/vendor/js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js
```

where it should be called in 
`Request URL: http://localhost:3000/vendor/js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js` 
not `/vendor/vendor/...`

Thus it produces `404 Not Found` error. How do I solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use absolute path in your src tag then. E.g.

```
  { src: '/vendor/js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js', body: true },
```

PS its bad idea to mix jquery and vue/nuxt